# Look up in Shell script variable similar to Set in c++

Tags: shell

I am deleting list of vm and associated network id.net1.net2,net3 etc.
ubuntu instances which is using these netwrok. some ubuntu vm is sharing common network also.

I am deleting the vm and then network one by one,since some of vm share common network it will try to delete already deleted network again and the script fails.

I need something similar to set variable in c++, and keep my deleted net id and each tim before delting net id I will find that in variable to ensure it is not already not deleted.

Do we have something in shell script to do look up.Any Suggestion how to accomplish look up alternatively.

**UPDATED**

I am using bash shell

Comment: What shell are you running and do you need variables to be visible to child processes?

Comment: @merlin2011 updated the question.I am using bash script

Comment: I'd just use a bash array. http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177139/34334